# Is the square of a measure a measure?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, solution-verification

Conside $(X, \Gamma, \mu)$ to be a measure space. Define $\nu(A) = \mu(A)^2$ for any $A \in \Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a topology. Is this $\nu$ a measure on $(X, \Gamma)$?

This is what I've done:
For $\nu$ to be a measure, we need $\nu(E)=\nu(E \cap A) + \nu(E \cap A^c)$. However, $\nu(E) = \mu(E)^2 = (\mu(E \cap A) + \mu(E \cap A^c))^2 = \mu(E \cap A)^2 + 2\mu(E \cap A)\mu(E \cap A^c) + \mu(E \cap A^c)^2$ which is not $\nu(E \cap A) + \nu(E \cap A^c)$ unless $\mu(E)=0$  $\forall E \in X$.

Does this seem correct or am I completely on the wrong track? Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me that you've got the gist of it, although $\mu$ being $0$ is not necessary: any measure $\mu$ where all the measurable sets are either negligible or of the same measure as $X$ will result in $\mu^2$ being a measure. That being said, the *topologies* which are also $\sigma$-algebras (id est, the ones where all the open subsets are closed) are quite pathological, therefore there might be something that I don't see.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\nu$ is a (finite, non-zero) measure and consider some $A\in \Gamma$.
Note that $$\begin{align}
[\mu(A)+\mu(A^c)]^2 &=\mu(A\cup A^c)^2\\
&= \nu(A\cup A^c) \\
&= \nu(A)+\nu(A^c)\\
&= \mu(A)^2+\mu(A^c)^2
\end{align}$$
Hence $\mu(A)\mu(A^c)=0$ and we have $\mu(A)=0$ or $\mu(A^c)=0$.

If $\mu(A)>0$, we have $\mu(A^c)=0$ thus $\mu(A)=\mu(X)$. Hence $\mu$ takes values in the set $\{0,\mu(X)\}$.

If $A$ and $B$ are such that $\mu(A)>0$ and $\mu(B)>0$, then $\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A)=\mu(B)=\mu(X)$, so $\mu$ must be quite pathological...

Comment: This depends on $\nu$ being a measure, as you have stated. I think a counter example might work. If E=[0,2] and A=[1,2], $\mu(E \cap A^c) \mu(E \cap A) \neq 0$ and we can say $\nu$ is not a measure. Is that correct?